# Excel import to MySQL: Date inserted as 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, date, phpexcel

I have used [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library to import an Excel file (.xlsx) and insert into MySQL. I'm facing two problems with the date field:

1- In the excel sheet I try to change the date format to the desired one. Upon saving, the cells show the format I need `(yyyy/mm/dd)` but when I double-click to edit them they again change back to how it was before `(mm/dd/yyyy)`.

2- When the file is imported to MySQL through PHPExcel all the columns are inserted correctly except the date column which inserts `0000-00-00`. The format in the Excelsheet is the same as in MySQL but it enters is all zeros.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value store in PHPExcel is an Excel serialized datetime value (a float, representing the number of days since 1/1/1900 or 1/1/9004 depending on whether Windows or Mac Calendar was used). Changing the format is simply changing the way this value is displayed.

You will either need to know in advance whether a cell contains a date, or test it using the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` method, and convert it appropriately. You can then either retrieve it using `getFormattedValue()` to return the value as a formatted string; or use the built-in conversion functions to convert it to a unix timestamp (`PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()`) or a PHP DateTime object (`PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()`) that you can then format using the standard PHP date formatting functions before using it in your MySQL INSERT/UPDATE statements.

Comment: Well shoot. I was converting my Excel sheets to CSV and then reading those but I guess in order to get accurate date values I'll have to use an Excel library after all

Answer (score 4):

Change the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd`, save the file as CSV and import that into your database.

Comment: Yes.  The format used for viewing in Excel has nothing to do with how it will be imported.  You need to change the actual value in excel file to yyyy-mm-dd, or make that transformation yourself before inserting into the DB.

Comment: @MikeBrant Well that's the problem. I change the actual value to the one I need and save. But it goes back the old one when edited again.